# Using $var = eval("2 + 2") does not evaluate as expected in PHP?

Tags: php, eval

I have tried many different combinations of code using the eval command. However my answer is always blank. Here is a simple one i tried.

```
$equation = "18 - (18 * 2) - 1";
$var = eval($equation);
echo "answer: " . $var;
```

I understand this does not need the eval code, but the real code I am working on does. It just always shows up blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Add `return` inside the evaluated statement, otherwise the `eval()` won't know what to return:

```
$equation = '2 + 2 * 2';
$var = eval("return $equation;");
```

Proof, that the above works: http://ideone.com/bTtIH

### About superiority of `return` vs. setting variable

More from [the documentation of `eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> `eval()` returns `NULL` unless `return` is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to `return` is returned.

In other words: there is no need to pollute the namespace, you can get what you want directly from what `eval()` returns.

Comment: One note: as nickb correctly noted, using `eval()` is discouraged. Try to avoid that and make sure 1) it is not user input, or 2) user input is correctly sanitized (preferably remove every letter, dollar sign and semicolon, if not having a better idea of sanitization).

Comment: "pollute the namespace"? The variable `$var` is set in this use-case either way - I don't see how using return does not "pollute the namespace" in the same way evaluating the variable does. Can you explain?

Comment: I like all the answers i have got. It has brought a new understanding to "Eval". But this one is the best for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the variable in the equation when you pass it to `eval()` to make it a valid and complete PHP expression:

```
$equation = "18 - (18 * 2) - 1";
eval(  '$var = ' . $equation . ';');
echo "answer: " . $var;
```

Or, you can return the value:

```
$var = eval(  'return ' . $equation . ';');
```

Now you can do `echo $var;`, as seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/PnREYn).

That being said, `eval()` use is usually discouraged, as the underlying problem is typically solved with other means.

Comment: Or `$var = eval('return ' . $equation . ';');`

Comment: @tigrang - Was adding it in as you commented :)

Comment: Oh, I see, so eval really runs an actual line of code instead of just a math equation. Ok, I just had a misunderstanding of what eval really done. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it runs actual lines of code - Be careful! A rule of thumb: Don't pass user input to `eval()`

Comment: Exactly, `return` is the way to go, not setting the variable. I have posted it more or less in the same time you added that part, because I did not agree with setting the variable within `eval()`. Anyway, your answer is valid.